# How do i store data in nextjs that is accessible from anywhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a nextjs app that needs to make api requests based on the user's inputs. Now the api requests need a token that I would like to generate at the start of the app and anytime that i need to based on the user data from getServerSideProps or something. I looked at a lot of options like saving it in cookies and session but i don't think for my use case that serves the purpose plus i would also like to learn how it should be done in nextjs.
Basically I need a

```
const data = {}
```

accessible from each request on the server so that when the server gets a request it does not have to refetch the data it already has.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you're trying to implement authentication, so I would strongly suggest reading the documentation available on [the NextJS website here](https://nextjs.org/docs/authentication).

Comment: no. Iam not trying to implement any auth. Basically my users will all essentially need access to the same data. But if one user decides to update something, I want that to be updated for all users if that makes sense.

Comment: @SakibulAlam, are you needing this data to be accessible instantly without refreshes?

A better description of what you're trying to achieve (maybe provide an example of what you'd expect to happen) would help others help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question.

#### Static data

If you have a static data, then your solution speaks for itself. Just export that so that all other files can import.

```
  const data = {}
  export default data
```

#### Client data

However in your case, you are speaking of static, but the data isn't, ex. the user info have to be resolved by one of the API and then stored somewhere as "static" from now on. So it's not static.

In case it's a client side (cookie), you can wire with that variable directly, such as in Next Auth. https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/example

#### Server data

If it's server data, it needs to be persisted via one of your API `/pages/api`. And after that yes, you can put it via `getServerSideProps` to the `_app.js`.

Comment: I actually do not have much use of an api so I was only looking for a way to store it in the `getServersideProps`. Because on each page, my plan was to have `getServerSideProps` refer to a global state like object. But if we are sure that there is no other way, I guess I will use ur suggestion.

Comment: The main purpose of `getServersideProps` is to wire with server resources. You could wire anything there, to me, it's similar to your own approach if the data is static.

Comment: thanks man, I went ahead with the api approach

Comment: `it needs to be persisted via one of your API /pages/api` Do you have any example ?

Comment: @Keytrap, the nextjs api by itself cannot persist value, but since api is backend, thus you can wire with other persist storage, such as database, hard drive etc.